# Export to Excel in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application where I need to export data to an excel spreadsheet.  Previously, in webforms apps, I used some code I found to render a GridView as an excel-compatible file.  This was quite handy. I was wondering what the quickest/most effective method would be to do this in MVC. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One simple option would be to create a view to render an XML-version of an Excel File. You could either use the new Office 2007 version, or the older 2003 version. We chose the 2003 version so that more people could use it, but that's up to you, of course.

[XML 2003 ref on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066.aspx#odc_xmlss_ss:Workbook)

[XML 2007 ref on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx)

Comment: I've used the same strategy to render RSS feeds, etc.  Works great.

Comment: We're using it several places now - web project creates a template for the end user so that we can re-import that file knowing that the format is correct. XML format is great!

Answer (score 20):

Here is a blog post from Stephen Walther entitled [ASP.NET MVC Tip #2 - Create a custom Action Result that returns Microsoft Excel Documents](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents.aspx)

Comment: This uses the old trick of writing an HTML document (basically a table) with an Excel mime type.  This is different than streaming a native Excel file.  That said, this is a fine way to do it for most application, since Excel handles HTML formatting pretty well.

Comment: It's fairly easy to change this to rendering as CSV if you don't need any fancy formatting. Just remember to double-quote all the fields if there's a possibility of commas showing up.

Comment: I attempted to go with the first option, hoping the XML approach would be cleaner or I'd learn something, but failed to find a complete tutorial on it. Spent a few hours messing around with that, then spent under an hour taking this approach, which was cleaner than I expected.

Comment: This is a method that I've seen, but I'm not happy with it. There are issues with the file that is generated and error messages that indicate that the file content is not the same as the intended type. My people hate that and now I have to find another way. :)

Comment: @Don I have had the same issues with that technique.

Comment: The technique is broken if you need to use fancy excel features like pivot tables.