# write excel in asp.net MVC1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image: Image of excel want to write]Hi all,
Please help me out, how to write headers and subheaders in excel using asp.netmvc1.
Please do see the image for reference. In image see from line no 13 to 15 i want to write 
in excel the same way.

Thanks
Nilanjan

Comment: You're trying to host excel on a web page?

Comment: you can look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301986/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following libraries :

- For excel 2007 and higher : http://epplus.codeplex.com/
- For excel 2002 and higher : http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/